# Reverse process of Injecting .Net Assemblies Into Unmanaged Processes

Tags: .net, assemblies, unmanaged

please give me the **reverse** procedure of 
**Injecting .Net Assemblies Into Unmanaged Processes** 
URL : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes

Answer (score 0):

It's know as P/Invoke (Platform Invoke). Here's a nice introduction to P/Invoke and Marshalling (the process of transferring state across the managed/unmanaged boundary).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx

Comment: Note that that's an ancient link. Be careful because links off of that article will lead you into more articles about .NET 1.1 - well over a decade old.